# laravel authentication with User class

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am using the code below to create a user in Laravel. When I log in with this user, it does not appear to be "authenticated" (even though the ID, password, and tenanted information has been entered correctly). Authenticated users go to a "home" page. This just goes back to the login page.

I noticed that when the user was created the "remember_token" of the "user" table was not filled out.

How can I fill out this field? How can I fix this so that users created using PHP are authenticated?

TIA

```
    $user = User::create([
    'name' => $contractor->getFirstName() . ' ' . $contractor->getLastName(),
    'email' => $contractor->getAsgnLogonID(),
    'password' => bcrypt($contractor->getAsgnPassword()),
    'tenantid' => $TENANTREFNO,
    'wavemakerid'=> $contractor->getKeyID(),
    ]);
```

Here is the **web.php** file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect()->route('login.showform');
});

Route::post('/login/custom', [
    'uses'  => 'Auth\LoginController@login',
    'as'    => 'login.custom'
    ]);

Route::get('/login/showform', [
    'uses'  => 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm',
    'as'    => 'login.showform'
    ]);

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');

Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');

Auth::routes();
```

Comment: can you add the rest of controller code.

Comment: are you using the `web` middleware on the routes?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. @ L.Kelmendi - the function is listed. @ Aboudeh87 have added the web.php file. TIA

Answer (score 0):

I made the changes below and was able to have the user logged in:

```
    if ( $password == $local_password )
        { 
            Auth::login($user);
            return redirect('/home'); 
        }
```